# Changing border thickness QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, style, formatting

Does any one know how to stylish a map using QGIS? Im working on some maps but when I project them in Stat Planet Plus the lines look very pointy, not curvy at all and it looks really unprofessional. I attach an image. Any tipps?

Thanks in advance.

PD if it works, the only files that I have are .shp, .prj, .qpj, .shp, .shx and .dbf.
PD 2 to project them in Stat Planet Plus I only use the .shp and .dbf files.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, it's your data's fault and has nothing to do with QGIS. It looks like a raster layer which was vectorized.

If you want, you can try to smoothen the polygon borders using generalization algorithms to get rid of the "stairs effect".

Comment: wow, ok. Do you know where could I get maps of the states and municipalities of Mexico that have not been vectorized? Please help...

Comment: check here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/34447/187